# laravel : How update a specific column with condition in controller?

Tags: laravel, database, model, controller, conditional-statements

I'm blocked on this problem and I need your help to find a solution.

So I'm building an exam system in laravel but I want to validate the exam with conditions. The conditions work but it updates all the rows related to the user's id. While I would like it to update only the line with related to the exam and user id to pass the result to 1.

In my controller I have this :

```
 if($note_theorique >= $eval->point_theorique && $note_pratique >= $eval->point_pratique && $tempspratique->temps <= $eval->temps_maximum){

                $resultatfinal = $stagiaire->resultatfinal;
                foreach($resultatfinal as $key => $resultat){
                    $result = $resultat->pivot;
                    $result->resultat = 1;
                    $result->save();
                }

            }
```

In my Stagiaire Model I have this relation :

```
public function resultatfinal(): BelongsToMany
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(Evaluation::class, 'evaluation_pivot', 'stagiaire_id', 'eval_id')
       ->withPivot('resultat');
   }
```

in my database I have this :

[image: Vue of database]

So the problem is :

The stagiaire_id (User) number 5 pass the eval_id number 21 and met the conditions to have 1 in resultat column.

I don't know how but it changes the second line and the third line to 1 instead of changing only the second line.

Do you have an idea to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with the sync() method?

```
// This should only set resultat = 1 on eval_id 21
$stagiaire->resultatfinal()->sync([21 => ['resultat' => 1], 26]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

Comment: Hello, do I use the foreach method with your proposition, because that's not working.

Comment: What does 26 represent in your code?

Comment: 21 & 26 represents the eval_ids. The associative array with the id 26 represent the data you want to insert in the pivot table. The id 21 have no data because you only want to keep the relation but not modifying any data in the pivot table.

Comment: Ok understand but hhe concern is that there will be a lot more evaluation in the future. I managed to change the data without the foreach. It works, but if I remove the 26, it erases the line of the eval_id 26.

Comment: Try with syncWithoutDetaching()